# Adding up a variable going through multiple methods (Java)

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to do a math test type program

The program specification is as follows.

> Generate 2 random numbers for each operation (user chooses 1 for addition, 2 for subtraction, 3 for multiplication, 4 for division, and 5 for modulo)  and you have to do the
>   same operation for at least 3 times
>
> Each case should keep track of and display the questions, answers,
>   score and time.
>
> 1. On each operation, when answer is correct, just say "Correct". For incorrect answers, should echo the question and provide the correct
>      answer.
> 2. Should keep the correct operation, number of questions, the question itself and the test time.
> 3. When all 3 questions for each operation are done, display the questions, with the user's answers, indicating correct or incorrect
>      answers, then display total number of questions, correct answers,
>      incorrect answers, the test time.
> 4. Now ask if the user wants to play again, i.e., to start all over again, using Confirmation box.
>
> At the end of the program, need the following displays:
>
> 1. Total number of questions (from all operations),
> 2. **Total correct and incorrect number of questions (not the question itself),**
> 3. Total test time from the very beginning till end.

Now, I have the entire program written. The only problem I'm having is keeping count of the correct answers through multiple trials. Like I can keep track of each individual rounds amount of questions, but I can't figure out how to add a rounds "correct answer count" to the previous round.

I am required to use methods, so the code is setup like

- main method
- selection method
- addition method
- subtraction method
- division method
- multiplication method
- modulo method

then it asks if you would like to repeat the entire process.

I have it all perfect except for being able to keep track of the correct answers through multiple rounds (trials).

Here is what my main method looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  int correct = 0;
  int option = 0;
  int wrong = 0;
  int count = 0;
  int num1 = 0;
  int num2 = 0;
  int selection = 0;

  do {
     switch (select(selection)) {
        case 1: 
           addDigits(num1, num2, correct);
           count = count + 3;
           break;
        case 2:
           subDigits(num1, num2, correct);
           count = count + 3;
           break;
        case 3:
           multDigits(num1, num2, correct);
           count = count + 3;
           break;
        case 4: 
           divDigits(num1, num2, correct);
           count = count + 3;
           break;
        case 5: 
           modDigits(num1, num2, correct);
           count = count + 3;
           break;
        default:System.out.print("Error: invalid entries\t" + count);  
     }
     option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Continue?");
  }
  while (option == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);

  long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  long testTime = endTime - startTime; 
  wrong = count - correct;       

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The total number of questions is: " + count +
        "\nThe total number of correct answers is: "  + "?????" +
        "\nThe total number of incorrect answers is: "  + "?????" +
        "\nThe total amount of time it took to take the test is: " + (testTime /1000) + " seconds");
  System.out.print(correct); //just a test
 }
```

and here is what one of my methods looks like (they are all basically the same):

```
public static void addDigits(int intA, int intB, int correctQuizAnswers) {

  int quizCount = 0;
  String output = " ";  
  long startQuizTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  long endQuizTime;
  long quizTime;  
  final int NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS = 3;

  while (quizCount < NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS){
     intA = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
     intB = (int)(Math.random() * 10);

     String answerString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (
        "what is " + intA + " + " + intB + "?");
     int answer = Integer.parseInt(answerString);

     quizCount++;

     if (answer == intA + intB) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "correct!");
        correctQuizAnswers++;

     }
     else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
           "Wrong, you entered: \n " + intA + " + " + intB + " = " + answerString + "\nThe correct answer is: \n" + intA + " + " + intB + " = " + (intA + intB));

     }

     output += "\n" + intA + " + " + intB + " = " + answerString +
        ((intA + intB == answer) ?  " correct" : " wrong"); 

  }
  endQuizTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  quizTime = endQuizTime - startQuizTime;


  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "the number of correct answers is:  " + correctQuizAnswers +
        "\nthe time it took to take the quiz is: " + quizTime / 1000 + " seconds\n" +
        output);       
 }
```

Comment: you are the man aarowaim, that did it for me, you are a saint =]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

declare class variables under the class declaration (where your main method resides):

```
public class myQuiz {
    int totalCorrect = 0;
    int totalIncorrect = 0;
```

after each trial finishes, call:

```
totalCorrect += correctQuizAnswers;
totalIncorrect += incorrectQuizAnswers;
```

incorrect and correct are the values from the last trial.

Comment: I was thinking i really only needed to keep track of the correct answers, because for incorrect i can just subtract correct from the count.

Comment: no problem! Don't forget to select a best answer because that'll let other people know that the answer is resolved (and reputation points are awarded)

Comment: I clicked the checkmark. Is that what you meant? sorry I'm new here.

Comment: why do are you referring class variables as global variables?

Comment: @user2310289 good point. Some of my C++ background surfaced when it shouldn't have. I'll make the correction. I'm a bit bummed by the downvotes for an otherwise relevant answer. Edit my answer next time and leave a friendly reminder, or flag my answer for edits if you can't. Downvotes are for when the quality of the answer is not acceptable. Seriously, flag it if it's that bad. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112659/to-downvote-or-not-to-downvote-or-to-wait `the downvote is for the wrong answer`

Comment: @Aarowaim As the OP is obviously a newbie, then using incorrect terms like global variables is un-acceptable.  Change your answer and you may have your downvote removed by someone.

Comment: @user2310289 I did. I'm not concerned with the downvote itself. I am concerned with the misunderstanding of a downvote's purpose. It is to evaluate the answer for adequacy, not perfection. I am expected to provide thorough, useful answers. Your expectation that I use terminology accurately reflects my answer's polish, not its validity. You are expected to upvote answers that address the question, and downvote answers that do not. By that standard, my answer is adequate.  I love SO, but not the newbie/expert dichotomy. The answer matters, not your pet peeves.

Comment: @Aarowaim Well let's hope that the people who down-voted notices and removes it.